# How can I fix the line-height in ordered list when the text breaks in multiple lines?

Tags: css

I have an ordered list and I used the 'line-height' on order to vertically align the icon/bullet I'm using with the text on the right.

The problem now is that when the text is long and breaks in multiple lines it's too close together and I cannot find a way to fix it.

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="fancy_list">
<li>Value 1</li>
<li>Value 2</li>
<li>Value 3</li>
<li>Value 4</li>
<li>Value 5</li>
</ul>
```

and here's the CSS:

```
.fancy_list {
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    }

    .fancy_list li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0 0 0 22px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    background: url(http://topgreekgyms.fitnessforum.gr/wp-content/themes/gbs-merchant-dashboard/img/red_sprite.png) -462px -164px repeat-y;
    line-height: 15px;
    height: 30px;
    display:block;
    float: left;
    word-spacing: 0.5px;
    letter-spacing: 0.4px;
    }
```

Also, here's a [link] to the page that actually has the issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fix I came up with is the following:

```
.fancy_list li {
     line-height: 1.5em;
     height: auto;
}
```

The line-height you were using was in fact too small for what you wanted. "1.5em" should be closer to what you were looking for.

Additionally, the height was set to 30px, which would force the list items to bleed on top of each other when there are two lines.

Hope that helped.

Comment: It absolutely did! Problem solved!
Thanks a lot TehTooya!

How can I align the check images though? When I change the code the text appears a bit lower.

Comment: Nice one! One might want to set a negative `margin-bottom` for the parent `ul` to exclude last line.

Answer (score 6):

```
.fancy_list li {
 padding-bottom:10px
```

}

Don't understand why this answer got negative response. This way you keep the right line-height, and able to adjust the space between list-items. This works perfectly for me :)

Comment: Works perfectly for me!  Line height adds spaces within a single line that has a large amount of text.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
ul {
  white-space: initial;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.fancy_list li {
     padding-bottom:10px

}
```

I think you are really expecting this